# python: excel: print in columns then start in next row

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I have data from beautifulsoup in the form of:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I want to get them in excel in the following format:

```
a b c d e f g 
h i j k l m n
o p q r s t u
etc...
```

when i print them in excel.

This is the code I have currently:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range (1,2):
   url ="https:...."
   response=requests.get(url,verify=False)
   soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text)
   g_data=soup.find_all("td",{"class"})
   results=[]
   for item in g_data:
             data=(item.text)
             results.append(data)
             wb=Workbook()
             ws=wb.active
             for row, i in enumerate(results):
                      columns_cell='A'
                      ws[column_cell+str(row+2)]=str(i)
             wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

UPDATED code:

```
for i in range (1,3):
url="https:.... .format(pagenum=i)
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text)
g_data=soup.find_all("td","class")
row=[]
wb=Workbook()
ws=wb.active
for idx, item in enumerate(g_data):
    row.append(item.text)
    if not idx % 7:
        ws.append(row)
        row=[]
wb.save("test2.xlsx")
```

[UPDATED RESULTS PICTURE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJSJl.jpg)

Finally this works:

```
for i in range (1,2)
url="https:... "
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text)
g_data=soup.find_all("td",{"class"})
results=[]
for item in g_data:
    results.append(item.text)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(results).reshape(20,7),columns("abcdefg"))
writer=pd.ExcelWriter('test4.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

The problem with this one is that its overwriting the previous results. Still a bit more work to do. but progress :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something a bit like this:

```
row = []
for idx, item in enumerate(g_data):
     row.append(item.text)
     if not idx % 6: # 7th element:
         ws.append(row)
         row = []
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the changes in the code and what you're seeing the in the cells.